# How can I report a user for accidentally creating another account?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, users

I was reviewing Suggested Edits at that time one user asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641250/fetching-meetings-using-ews), and the same user suggested an edit to the question using another account. I think the user is new and opened both account within 10 days of each other.

I don't think the user knew that he had made this mistake. Is there any way I can report this so that a moderator can remove the other account? I tried to find such an option but couldn't see any.

Comment: I think he's referring to this one http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7690710

Comment: @Roombatron5000 yes exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just `flag` the question with `other (needs ♦ moderator attention)
This question needs a moderator's attention.` and when they ask `Please describe whats wrong`  you can type down the same.

That should take care of it

Comment: I think it is about question flag/report not user.

Comment: No, every other flag is for questions, but for other unspecifiable flags, we use the other option.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a comment to the question suggesting that the accounts need to be merged (the user is still active on that question) that includes the following text:

> See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.